# Как сделать так, чтобы выполнялось не только первое if?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в программировании, вот хочу сделать игру камень ножницы бумага, но выполняется только первое if от "u", т.е. if u == "к":
Ну я не знаю как это объяснить, у кого много времени, протестируйте этот код и узнайте сами, я новичок, поэтому не знаю как всё объяснить

````
def kmb():
   print("добро пожаловать в игру камень ножницы бумага")
   while True:
       list = ["камень", "ножницы", "бумага"]
       c = random.choice(list)
       u = input("камень, ножницы, или бумага?(к,н,б)")
       if c == "камень":
           print("компьютер выбрал камень")
           if u == "к":
               print("ничья")
               if u == "н":
                   print("вы проиграли")
                   if u == "б":
                       print("вы победили")
       if c == "ножницы":
           print("компьютер выбрал ножницы")
           if u == "к":
               print("вы победили")
               if u == "н":
                   print("ничья")
                   if u == "б":
                       print("вы проиграли")
       if c == "бумага":
           print("компьютер выбрал бумагу")
           if u == "к":
                   print("вы проиграли")
                   if u == "н":
                       print("вы победили")
                       if u == "б":
                           print("ничья")
       if u == "stop":
           main()```
````

Comment: 1. https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/python-if-elif-else 2. Перечитай в учебнике главу про отступы в коде.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, мне помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая то, что сказал **Эникейщик**, получаем такой код:

```
import random

def kmb():
   print("добро пожаловать в игру камень ножницы бумага")
   while True:
       list = ["камень", "ножницы", "бумага"]
       c = random.choice(list)
       u = input("камень, ножницы, или бумага? ( к, н, б ) ")
       if c == "камень":
           print("компьютер выбрал камень")
           if u == "к":
               print("ничья")
           if u == "н":
               print("вы проиграли")
           if u == "б":
               print("вы победили")
       if c == "ножницы":
           print("компьютер выбрал ножницы")
           if u == "к":
               print("вы победили")
           if u == "н":
               print("ничья")
           if u == "б":
               print("вы проиграли")
       if c == "бумага":
           print("компьютер выбрал бумагу")
           if u == "к":
             print("вы проиграли")
           if u == "н":
             print("вы победили")
           if u == "б":
             print("ничья")
       if u == "stop":
           main()

kmb()           
'''
Lover ツ
'''
```

Comment: если идет серия взаимоисключающих if, то лучше использовать if-elif. Т.е. ``if u == "к":`` ... ``elif u == "н":`` ... ``elif u == "б":``. Ну про камень/ножницы/бумага тоже.

Comment: и добавить ``else: print("неправильный ввод")``, если игрок ввел что-то другое.

Comment: Вот это уже более удобно, спасибо за усовершенствованный код:3

Comment: @Loverツ глянь сколько у меня репутации